# Table display in Firefox does not match Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, html-table

I cannot get Firefox to display a table as accurately displayed in Chrome. Someone advised me that Firefox requires the width specified for the table and cells.  Can someone please review the HTML below and determine if the cell width needs to be specified on each `<td>` code or what else I must do to get Firefox to display the table as Chrome does?

```
<table style="width: 639px;" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
<tbody>

<tr valign="middle">

<td style="width: 213px; vertical-align: middle;"><a href="http://www.sponsor1namehere.com/" target="_blank"><img class=" size-medium wp-image-15070 aligncenter" src="http://www.domainname1here.com/updates/wp-content/uploads/SponsorLogo1.jpg" alt="SponsorLogo1" width="300" height="219" /></a></td>
<td style="width: 213px; vertical-align: middle;"><a href="http://www.sponsor2namehere.com/" target="_blank"><img class=" aligncenter" style="width: 80%;" src="http://sponsorlogo2.jpg" alt="SponsorLogo2" border="0" /></a></td>
<td style="width: 213px; vertical-align: middle;"><a href="http://sponsor3namehere.com/" target="_blank"><img class=" aligncenter" style="width: 80%;" src="http://www.domainname3here.org/updates/wp-content/uploads/SponsorLogo3.jpg" alt="sponsorlogo3" /></a></td>
```

```
<tr valign="middle">

<td style="width: 32%; vertical-align: middle;"><a href="http://www.sponsor4.com/" target="_blank"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-14980" src="http://www.Sponsor4.org/updates/wp-content/uploads/Sponsor4.jpg" alt="Sponsor4_300W" width="300" height="126" /></a></td>
<td style="width: 32%; vertical-align: middle;"><a href="http://www.Sponsor5.org/" target="_blank"><img class=" aligncenter" style="width: 80%;" src="http://www.Sponsor5.org/updates/wp-content/uploads/Sponsor5.png" alt="Sponsor5" /></a></td>
<td style="width: 32%; vertical-align: middle;"><a href="https://www.Sponsor6.com/" target="_blank"><img class=" size-medium wp-image-15072 aligncenter" src="http://www.Sponsor6.org/updates/wp-content/uploads/Sponsor6300x201.jpg" alt="Sponsor6" width="300" height="201" /></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```